# Spark Dataframe returns an inconsistent value on count()

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pypark to perform some computations on data obtained from a PostgreSQL database. My pipeline is something similar to this:

```
limit = 1000
query = "(SELECT * FROM table LIMIT {}) as filter_query"
df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://path/to/db") \
        .option("dbtable", query.format(limit)) \
        .option("user", "user") \
        .option("password", "password") \
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
df.count() # 1000
```

So far, so good. The problem starts when I perform some transformations on the data:

```
counted_data = spark.sql("SELECT column1, count(*) as count FROM table GROUP BY column1").orderBy("column1")
counted_data.count() # First value

counted_data_with_additional_column = counted_data.withColumn("column1", my_udf_function)
counted_data_with_additional_column.count() # Second value, inconsistent with the first count (should be the same)
```

The first transformation alters the number of rows, (the value should be <= 1000). However, the second one does not, it just adds a new column. How can it be that I am getting a different result for `count()`?

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is actually quite simple, but a bit tricky. Spark *might* perform additional reads to the input source (in this case a database). Since some other process is inserting data in the database, these additional calls read slightly different data than the original read, causing this inconsistent behaviour. A simple call to `df.cache()` after the read disables further reads. I figured this out by analyzing the traffic between the database and my computer, and indeed, some further SQL commands where issued that matched my transformations. After adding the `cache()` call, no further traffic appeared.

Comment: Please remember that you shouldn't depend on cache for correctness. Cache can evicted at any time without you even being aware of that.

Comment: @user8371915 Good point. I might persist the read data to disk before further computations or make sure that the query is guaranteed to always return the same data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Limit 1000, you might be getting different 1000 records on each execution. And since you will be getting different records each time, the result of aggregation will be different. In order to get the consistent behaviour with Limit you can try following approaches.

1. Either try to cache your dataframe with cahce() or Persist method, which will ensure that spark will use same data till the time it will be available in memory.
2. But better approach could be to sort the data based on some unique column and then get the 1000 records, which will ensure that you will get the same 1000 records each time.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I actually wrote the question to document this behaviour, which does not only happen after running the entire computation, but also on the intermediate steps. I went with the `cache` option, since the query is just an example for a situation where this might happen.